# Loading tensorfow model from native file system using TensorflowJS 2.0.1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

Am trying to load a pre-trained Keras model to my small react-App. Since with the 2.0 version of TensorFlow, few things were added and changed. I would like to know how one should load the model from the native file system.

1. First I import tensorflowJS

```py
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
```

2. My directory structure
   model.json and all .bin files required are located in the same directory as my App.js from which am referring to them.
3. Load the pre-trained model - [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load)

```py
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel("file://model.json");
```

Unfortunately am getting failed to fetch error. Can anyone explain me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the path to the model weights and JSON using require()

```
const modelJSON = require("../model/model.json");

const modelWeights = require("../model/group1-shard1of1.bin");

const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights))
```

Edit in the case of you having multiple bin files you can only use one bin file with one model.json

The code below converts your keras model to a single bin file and model.json

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras --weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000 path_to_model.h5 path_to_save
```

Comment: Any ideas how to read bin file from file system successfully? I read group.bin file from file system as base64 string then convert it to Uint8Array but bundleResourceIO expects number type for weight file.

Answer (score 0):

expo projects doesnt support such structure.

1. save your model folder in assets
2. import liabrary "expo-asset" from [expo documentatio](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/)
3. then call your code as

const modelJson = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/model/model.json'))

const modelWeights = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/model/weights.bin'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).